# Calculating percentages of a percent of a percent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

A student is taking a class where $40\%$ of his or her grade is based on homework and the remaining $60\%$ is based on tests. There are a total of 12 homework assignments and 4 tests. The student completes $9/12$ assignments with a perfect score and all 4 tests with a perfect score. What is his final grade? I first converted the homework assignments into a decimal 
$$ 9/12 = .75 $$
since their homework is 40% of their grade:
$$ .75 * .4 = .3$$
which I then added to the final quiz percentage to get a total grade for the class:
$$ .3 + .6 = .9 $$
$$.9 * 100 = 90 $$

The student completed the class with an A(90%), however I'm not sure this calculation is correct. Can someone please verify?

Comment: alan - for some reason your first use of '40 percent' is showing as 40. Might make a quick edit to fix this.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate that, I am unsure how to display percent signs with MathJax.

Comment: fixed it.  I had to make a few arbitrary changes since there is a minimum amount of characters I must change to submit an edit.

Comment: @AlanZ2223:  to display percent signs in MathJax you need to escape them with a backslash. so 60\% gives $60\%$ when put between dollar signs.  That is generally true, for dollar signs, braces, etc

Comment: It is correct.${}$

Comment: Also - your calculation is correct.

Comment: Thank you. I hope someone can find this useful.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.  Another way to think about it is to have $100$ points available.  Each test is $\frac 14$ of $60\%$ of $100$ or $15$ points.  Each homework is $\frac 1{12}$ of $40\%$ of $100$ or $\frac {10}3$ points.  The student has accumulated $4 \cdot 15 + 9 \cdot \frac {10}3=90$ points.